# Startup Error: Java failed to startup successfully. Please make sure you have 32-bit Java 8 installed

Tags: sql-workbench-j

I am trying to launch SQL Workbench/J and get the error.

Java Development Kit 8 is installed. I was able to use Workbench before without any issues.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: You say that JDK 8 is installed, but is it **32-bit**? The error message says specifically that it must be the 32-bit version.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, you're right. It is JDK 64. In sqlworkbech folder I also see 2 files SQLWorkbench and SQLWorkbench64. Now when I switch to SQLWorkbench64 it works fine. I am still not sure why I started getting this error. Many thanks.

[Per docs](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/install.html): To start SQL Workbench/J on the Windows® platform, the supplied SQLWorkbench.exe for a 32bit Java runtime or SQLWorkbench64.exe for a 64bit Java runtime can be used to start the program. The file sqlworkbench.jar has to be located in the same directory as the exe files, otherwise it does not work.